# insert range of information based on duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to do a code that will find duplicate bettwen a document and a master list and if there is duplicate, will write information to the left and right of said word in the document.

the code bellow is half working

```
Sub remplissage_FR_3_63()
        
        'worksheet
        Set remplissage = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Remplissage")
        Set couple = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR-3-63_Couples")
        
        'tableau document
        Dim tableau_co As range
        Dim nbrligne_co As Integer
        Set tableau_co = couple.range("c8:c9")
        nbrligne_co = tableau_co.Columns.Count
        
        'tableau master list
        Dim tableau_ca As range
        Dim nbrligne_ca As Integer
        Set tableau_ca = couple.range("c109:c110")
        nbrligne_ca = tableau_ca.Columns.Count
        
        Dim nomcomposant As range
        Dim nommaster As range
        
        Dim nca As range
        Dim ncb As range
        Dim nma As range
        Dim nmb As range
          
        For Each nomcomposant In tableau_co
                
            For Each nommaster In tableau_ca
            
                If nomcomposant.Value = nommaster.Value Then
    
                    Set nca = nomcomposant.Offset(0, -2)
                    Set ncb = nomcomposant.Offset(0, 1)
                    Set nma = nommaster.Offset(0, -2)
                    Set nmb = nommaster.Offset(0, 1)
                                       
                    couple.nca.Value = couple.nma.Value
                    couple.ncb.Value = couple.nmb.Value
                    
                    
                End If
        
            Next nommaster
        
        Next nomcomposant
    
End Sub
```

range of ("c8:c9") and ("c109:c110") is short because i am testing, both range will be actualy longer.

this part of the code dont work

```
Set nca = nomcomposant.Offset(0, -2)
Set ncb = nomcomposant.Offset(0, 1)
Set nma = nommaster.Offset(0, -2)
Set nmb = nommaster.Offset(0, 1)

couple.nca.Value = couple.nma.Value
couple.ncb.Value = couple.nmb.Value
```

i used this line for test purpose as replacement for those that dont work and the code work

```
range("ar3") = 10
```

since there is fused cell i use .value because i know it work.

what would need to be done to make the NCA, NCB, NMA and NMB work?

[image: main document]

[image: master list]

Comment: Just `nca.Value` not `couple.nca.Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Dim nca As range
Dim nma As range

Set nca = nomcomposant.Offset(0, -2)
Set nma = nommaster.Offset(0, -2)

nca.Value = nma.Value
```

`nca` (for example) is a Range-type variable: it's not a method of `couple`

Comment: if i run the code from another worksheet it doesn’t work thought, would there be a way to make this kind of code work from another worksheet? else the code work as intended. edit : most code from my excel file run trough trough 1 button

Comment: "doesn’t work" doesn't tell us anything about what happens when you run your code. If you get an error, what is that error and on which line of code? Is this code in the same workbook as the worksheets you're using?  If Yes then use `Thisworkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: NVM. it is actually working from other worksheet as intended. thanks